# Nginx and flask static directory - CSS not linking correctly

Tags: python, html, css, nginx, flask

This is my static directory:

- /var/www/myapp/app/static/css
- /var/www/myapp/app/static/js
- /var/www/myapp/app/static/img

In my nginx config I have this:

```
location /static {
    alias /var/www/myapp/app/static;
    expires 30d;
    access_log off;
}
```

In my template I then use something like this:

```
<img height="60" src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.jpg')}}"></img>
```

However, it doesn't render. When I view the source of my HTML page running under flask it renders it like this:

```
<img height="60" src="/static/img/logo.jpg">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you try to access the image (or is it css?) directly in the browser?

Comment: @PaulRooney if i visit either of the two urls below I get a 404: www.site.com/static/css/style.css or www.site.com/css/style.css

Comment: Is your root variable in the nginx server block correctly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx_server.conf example

```
    root  /var/www/website/;

# make path root + location `name` = root + /static/ = real path
location /static/  {
    alias /var/www/website/static/;
    expires 30d;

}
```

Enjoy.